# Error in using stanford core nlp

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I need to perform coreference resolution using Stanford core nlp. i downloaded version 3.3.0.the code i used is shown below.there is an error at getCorefMentions() as it is not found. i dont know wat jar files nee to include to remove this error.

```
package unlpro;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.NamedEntityTagAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.PartOfSpeechAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.TextAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;
import edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.SemanticGraph;
import edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.SemanticGraphCoreAnnotations.CollapsedCCProcessedDependenciesAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.Tree;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.TreeCoreAnnotations.TreeAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import edu.stanford.nlp.dcoref.CorefCoreAnnotations.CorefChainAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.TreeCoreAnnotations.TreeAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.dcoref.CorefChain;
import edu.stanford.nlp.dcoref.CorefChain.CorefMention;
import edu.stanford.nlp.dcoref.CorefCluster;
import edu.stanford.nlp.dcoref.Document;
import edu.stanford.nlp.dcoref.Mention;
/**
 *
 * @author Soundri
 */
public class NewClass {



  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
  {

   Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");
    ;                   // The path for a file that includes a list of demonyms 

    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

    // read some text in the text variable
   // String text ="Ram and Lakshman went to the market he purchased";
        String text ="The Revolutionary War occurred during the 1700s and it was the first war in the United States";


    // create an empty Annotation just with the given text

    Annotation document = new Annotation(text);

    // run all Annotators on this text
    pipeline.annotate(document);

    // these are all the sentences in this document
    // a CoreMap is essentially a Map that uses class objects as keys and has values with custom types
    List<CoreMap> sentences = document.get(SentencesAnnotation.class);

    for(CoreMap sentence: sentences) {
      // traversing the words in the current sentence
      // a CoreLabel is a CoreMap with additional token-specific methods
      for (CoreLabel token: sentence.get(TokensAnnotation.class)) {
        // this is the text of the token
        String word = token.get(TextAnnotation.class);
        // this is the POS tag of the token
        String pos = token.get(PartOfSpeechAnnotation.class);
        // this is the NER label of the token
        String ne = token.get(NamedEntityTagAnnotation.class);       
      }

      // this is the parse tree of the current sentence
      Tree tree = sentence.get(TreeAnnotation.class);

      // this is the Stanford dependency graph of the current sentence
      SemanticGraph dependencies = sentence.get(CollapsedCCProcessedDependenciesAnnotation.class);

       System.out.println("Dependencies "+dependencies);
    }

    // This is the coreference link graph
    // Each chain stores a set of mentions that link to each other,
    // along with a method for getting the most representative mention
    // Both sentence and token offsets start at 1!
    Map <Integer, CorefChain> graph = document.get(CorefChainAnnotation.class); 

    System.out.println("Graph "+graph);
//    for(int i=1;i<graph.size();i++)
//    {
//         System.out.println(graph.get(i));
//    }
   for(Map.Entry<Integer, CorefChain> entry : graph.entrySet()) {
            CorefChain c = entry.getValue();

            //this is because it prints out a lot of self references which aren't that useful
            if(c.getCorefMentions().size() <= 1)
                continue;

            CorefMention cm = c.getRepresentativeMention();
            String clust = "";
            List<CoreLabel> tks = document.get(SentencesAnnotation.class).get(cm.sentNum-1).get(TokensAnnotation.class);
            for(int i = cm.startIndex-1; i < cm.endIndex-1; i++)
                clust += tks.get(i).get(TextAnnotation.class) + " ";
            clust = clust.trim();
            System.out.println("representative mention: \"" + clust + "\" is mentioned by:");

            for(CorefMention m : c.getCorefMentions()){
                String clust2 = "";
                tks = document.get(SentencesAnnotation.class).get(m.sentNum-1).get(TokensAnnotation.class);
                for(int i = m.startIndex-1; i < m.endIndex-1; i++)
                    clust2 += tks.get(i).get(TextAnnotation.class) + " ";
                clust2 = clust2.trim();
                //don't need the self mention
                if(clust.equals(clust2))
                    continue;

                System.out.println("\t" + clust2);
//
```

i included all jar files in that package. i am new to this i dont know if some changes need to be done in code

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are calling `getCorefMentions()` on a variable whose class doesn't declare such a method.

The javadoc for `CorefChain` is [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/dcoref/CorefChain.html).

I don't claim to understand either Stanford NLP, or what you are trying to do with it, but one possible fix might be to replace

```
    c.getCorefMentions()
```

with

```
    c.getCoreMentionMap().values()
```

I'll leave it to you to decide if that makes sense ...